# std::vector<T>::emplace_back on an rvalue reference

Tags: c++, emplace

I have the following function inside a class

```
  void add_state(std::string &&st) {
    state.emplace_back(st);           // state is a vector
  }
```

`st` is an l-value (rvalue reference to a string in this case) based on my understanding. If, I want to move `st` into the last element in `state`, should I be using `state.emplace_back(std::move(st))`? What happens if I leave it the way it's written above?

## EDIT 1 (example of how `add_state` is called):

```
// do a series of operations to acquire std::string str
add_state(std::move(str)); 
// also note that str will never be used again after passing it into add_state
```

Would it be better if I made `add_state(std::string &st)` instead? In this case, I think I can just simply call it with `add_state(str)`?

Comment: I would like to hear more about the use of r-value references, std::move and `emplace_back`, because it seems like and important use case. If I have a function call returning a value, and I want to store it in an array, how to I ensure the objects are instantiated straight inside the array? `vec.emplace_back(mkobj());`? `obj&& o=mkobj(); vec.emplace_bac(std::move(o))``? When is it even necessary, an when can I be sure it will be optimized already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [...] should I be using `state.emplace_back(std::move(st))`?

Yes.

> What happens if I leave it the way it's written above?

You have correctly identified that `st` is an lvalue, so it gets copied.

> Would it be better if I made `add_state(std::string &st)` instead? In this case, I think I can just simply call it with `add_state(str)`?

You could, but you shouldn't. `std::move` is just type juggling, it does not do anything by itself (in particular, it doesn't move anything). The actual operation happens inside `std::string::basic_string(std::string &&)` which is called by `emplace_back` after it receives the `std::string &&`. Making your own parameter an lvalue reference has no effect other than surprising the caller, who gets their `std::string` eaten without an `std::move` on their part.

Comment: So let me give some more background because I'm not sure if I'm doing this optimally. When calling `add_state`, I had to cast an `lvalue` to an `xvalue` and pass this into `add_state`. Note that the argument being passed into `add_state` will never be used again. And then inside `add_state`, I have to perform another `std::move`, as you just stated. So that's 2 moves. Could I achieve the same behavior if I simply passed the lvalue by plain vanilla reference, and then move it inside the function? In this case, I would only be performing 1 move? I'll edit this into the OP to make it clearer.