# Is it still necessary to use std move even if auto && has been used

Tags: c++11, stl, move, emplace

As we know, STL usually offered two kinds of functions to insert an element: insert/push and emplace.

Let's say I want to emplace all of elements from one container to another.

```
for (auto &&element : myMap)
{
    anotherMap.emplace(element);  // vs anotherMap.empalce(std::move(element));
}
```

In this case, if I want to call the emplace, instead of insert/push, must I still call `std::move` here or not?

Comment: For this simple case, you could also use `move(begin(myMap), end(mayMap), inserter(anotherMap, end(anotherMap)))` (insert `std::` where appropriate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you indeed want to move all elements from `myMap` into `anotherMap` then yes you must call `std::move()`. The reason is that `element` here is still an lvalue. Its type is rvalue reference as declared, but the expression itself is still an lvalue, and thus the overload resolution will give back the lvalue reference constructor better known as the copy constructor.

This is a very common point of confusion. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346138/stdvectortemplace-back-on-an-rvalue-reference) question.

Always keep in mind that `std::move` doesn't actually do anything itself, it just guarantees that the overload resolver will see an appropriately-typed rvalue instead of an lvalue associated with a given identifier.